# Getting rid of facet_grid labels on those gray boxes?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label, facet

What I'd like it's to remove those labels on the right side, the ones on gray boxes on the side. I'll give an example:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(cyl ~ .)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Juan

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547487/r-removing-facet-wrap-labels-completely-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The following would do that:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(cyl ~ .)
p <- p +theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

Without rectangles

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(cyl ~ .)
p <- p + theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
   strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps like this? `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + facet_grid(cyl ~ .) + theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())`

Comment: This is a good pointer, however, there are still gray rectangles on the side, any way to erase those?

Comment: Nice one @FredrikKarlsson! That's definitively it.

Comment: @Fredrik Karlsson: thank you for your suggestion, I updated that in the answer box, if your permit of course ;-)

Comment: Is it me or this is not working for the following (lifted from ggplot manual): ``ggplot(economics_long, aes(date, value)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y", nrow = 2) +
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
              strip.text.y = element_blank())``