# Remove Only One of Two facet_grid() X Labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a variant of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303577/getting-rid-of-facet-grid-labels-on-those-gray-boxes) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/how-to-change-facet-labels) that I haven't found a solution to.

Using `mtcars` as an example I want a plot similar to the following

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) +
geom_point() +
facet_grid(am ~ gear + carb)
```

However, I want the facet x labels associated with the "carb" variable to be removed while keeping the label for the "gear" variable. The following gets at what I want, but puts "NA" in it's place rather than completely removing it.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) +
geom_point() +
facet_grid(am ~ gear + carb, labeller = labeller(carb = "")
```

Of course, using `theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())` doesn't work for me either since I want to keep the label for the "gear" variable.

Ultimately, I want to grid using both x layers but for me the label for the second x layer doesn't hold any meaning so it's distracting to include in the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons I also don't understand, the following seems to work. The function just returns a vector of empty strings of equal length as the input.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(am ~ gear + carb, 
             labeller = labeller(carb = function(x) {rep("", length(x))}))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Interesting. I skimmed over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913120/7753022) too quickly which seems to take a similar approach. This works perfectly, thank you!