# Mix empty and bquote-d facet labels using a labeller in ggplot2 >= 2.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

Prior to the 2.0, in ggplot2 I could use `element_blank` and `labeller` to label only rows or columns in `facet_grid`, like:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl))
g + facet_grid(vs ~ gear, labeller=labeller(vs = element_blank(),
                                             gear = label_bquote(mu == .(x))))
```

Now, with `ggplot2` version 2.0, this doesn't work, giving

```
Error in if (attr(labels, "facet") == "wrap") { :
  argument is of length zero
Calls: <Anonymous> ... lapply -> FUN -> <Anonymous> -> x -> resolve_labeller
```

Although the [improvements to `label_bquote`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/) are great, is there any way to make the above work with a `labeller`?

**I've tried:**

1) passing `NULL`, but facets default to `label_value` (as per `?label_bquote`)

```
  g + facet_grid(vs ~ gear,
               labeller = label_bquote(
                            rows = NULL,
                            cols = mu == .(gear)))
```

2) passing `element_blank` but facets say `element_blank()`

```
g + facet_grid(vs ~ gear,
           labeller = label_bquote(
                        rows = element_blank(),
                        cols = mu == .(gear)))
```

3) wrapping `element_blank` in `as_labeller`

```
g + facet_grid(vs ~ gear, labeller=labeller(.rows = as_labeller(element_blank()),
                                            .cols = label_bquote(mu == .(gear))))
```

**Note** it is possible to [remove facet labels after the fact using theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547487/r-removing-facet-wrap-labels-completely-in-ggplot2)

```
g + facet_grid(vs ~ gear,
               labeller = label_bquote(cols = mu == .(gear))) +
    theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

But I'd like to do it with a `labeller`.

Comment: `rows=""` gets rid of the labels, but you'll still have a blank grey strip.

Comment: awesome! I thought i'd tried that but clearly not o_O. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `rows=""` or `` rows = ` ` ``. This will get rid of the labels, though you'll still have a blank gray strip.

For clarity, this is the full command:

```
 g + facet_grid(vs ~ gear,
                labeller = label_bquote(rows = "",
                                        cols = mu == .(gear)))
```

You can of course also get rid of the gray strip by adding `theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())`.