# How do I Use "Symbol = Numeric" and "Character = Numeric" in Ggplot2 Label

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want the column header and row header of this plot to be `phi = 0.8, phi = 0.9, phi = 0.95` and `sd = 1, sd = 3, sd = 5, sd = 10` respectively. The `phi` should appear as the Greek letter symbol while the `sd` remains the English letter.

```
## simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
set.seed(289805)
x1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(671086)
x2 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(799837)
x3 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(289805)
x4 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(671086)
x5 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(799837)
x6 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(289805)
x7 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(671086)
x8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(799837)
x9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(289805)
x10 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(671086)
x11 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(799837)
x12 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
xx <- 1:10

df <- data.frame(xx, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12)
reshapp <- reshape2::melt(df, id = "xx")

NEWDAT <- data.frame(y = reshapp$value, x = reshapp$xx, sd = rep(rep(c(sd=1, sd=3, sd=5, sd=10), each = 10), each = 3),phi = rep(rep(c(.8, .9, .95), each = 10), 4))

ggplot(NEWDAT, aes(x = x, y = y)) +  geom_line() +  geom_point() + labs(x = 'lb', y = 'RMSE') + facet_grid(sd ~ phi,  scales = "free_y") +
  theme_bw() + ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))
```

[image: Facet Grid]

Comment: There's no need to set the pseudo-RNG seed so many times, one, at the beginning of the script is enough.

Comment: Each of the seeds is unique just as each of the series is.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but if you set it only once the values of the 2nd series will be different than the 1st series values. And the same for all others.

Comment: Ok, next time. I need an answer to my question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `plotmath` using only standard characters, no special escape sequences.

```
NEWDAT <- data.frame(y = reshapp$value, x = reshapp$xx, sd = rep(rep(c(sd=1, sd=3, sd=5, sd=10), each = 10), each = 3),phi = rep(rep(c(.8, .9, .95), each = 10), 4))
NEWDAT$sd <- factor(NEWDAT$sd, levels = NEWDAT$sd, labels = paste("sd ==", NEWDAT$sd))
NEWDAT$phi <- with(NEWDAT, factor(phi, levels = phi, labels = paste("phi ==", phi)))

ggplot(NEWDAT, aes(x = x, y = y)) +  
  geom_line() +  
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00)) +
  labs(x = 'lb', y = 'RMSE') + 
  facet_grid(
    sd ~ phi, 
    scales = "free_y",
    labeller = label_parsed
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Edited to account for the refactor in the third line of code]

A quick fix is to either create or rename the faceted key with Phi expressed in UTF8 encoding, plus the creation of the string you want (ie. "Phi|SD = N")
In this case I create a new variable:

```
NEWDAT %>% 
    mutate(phi_label = paste0("\U03D5 = ", phi), #"\U03D5" represents the character "ϕ"
           sd_label = fct_reorder(.f = paste0("sd =", sd), .x = sd)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +  geom_line() +  geom_point() + labs(x = 'lb', y = 'RMSE') + 
    facet_grid(sd_label ~ phi_label,  scales = "free_y") +
    theme_bw() + ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))
```

[image]

Comment: Check why is it that your output is `sd = 1, sd = 10, sd = 3, sd = 5`?

Comment: Done, Daniel. Indeed, as the lab_sd is now a categorical rather than numerical variable, we need to refactor it to get the expected numerical increments in the rows of the facet.

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `sd_label`.
i `sd_label = forecast::fct_reorder(.f = paste0("sd =", sd), .x = sd)`.
x 'fct_reorder' is not an exported object from 'namespace:forecast'

Comment: Please restart your R season.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is this: Use this `facet_grid` call instead of the one you're using right now.

```r
  facet_grid(sd ~ phi,  scales = "free_y", labeller = . %>% label_both(sep = " = "))
```

### Using `bquote`

```r
  facet_grid(sd ~ phi,  scales = "free_y", 
             labeller = 
               label_bquote(rows = sigma == .(sd), cols = phi == .(phi))
  )
```

This will yield the right labels.

Answer inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586853/mix-empty-and-bquote-d-facet-labels-using-a-labeller-in-ggplot2-2-0)

Comment: The `label_bquote` version should give you exactly what you wanted.